# Power Bi date error when importing excel file

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

SO when I import this excel file with **invoice_date** column as **12/1/2010 8:26** there is an error popup and when I click on view errors it takes me to Power Query Editor where all the values in the date column are displayed as an error.

[image: PowerBI Error Screenshot]

I tried changing type using Locale but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you may try changing Windows Regional settings.

day/month/year

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Answer (score 0):

Is there data formatted in excel as a date? If so, change it to text and import again. that way you can try and convert to datetime field from there and get more information on why it isnt converting if it doesnt.

Also, review your data. Has something got into the datetime column that isnt datetime?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by splitting the date/time column in the PowerQuery transform stage in a Date column and a Time column.